# Codeigniter language segments in routing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "front/$1"; // front
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1"; // admin
```

i want to make url like this:

```
mysite.com/en/somecontroller/somemethod

mysite.com/ru/somecontroller/somemethod

etc...
```

i guess something like this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "front/$1"; // front
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "front/$2";

$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1"; // admin
$route['(:any)/admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$2";
```

but I get errors when the first segment is language, CI thinks that is a controller

Comment: why not add the parameter after every controller and not before the controller?

Comment: you mean something like mysite.com/myController/method/language ??, i tought if it will be in the beginning it will be more beautyfull)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using CodeIgniter's *[language class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html)*, then this [URI Language Identifier](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier) class extension should do exactly what you want.

> This language class extension allows you to automatically prefix all site urls with a language abbreviation that is pre-defined in your config file or from a link and automatically load the corresponding language translation file, the route will then be corrected by the route regex for everything to work as normal.