# How can i add /en for all routs in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

How can i add /en for all routs in codeigniter ?
i have this route :

```
$route['^en/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^en$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

How can it be repeated for all the content of the site without adding it manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codeigniter language segments in routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800191/codeigniter-language-segments-in-routing)

Comment: its not working for all controllers

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier) which is in the answer of the above link i gave you has pretty good documentation, you should read up on it.